Type struct DLOImplementation.LendInfo[] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct DLOImplementation.LendInfo[] memory
I am writing a test case to call this function getActiveOrders in Foundry.
DebitaLendOfferFactory:
contract DebitaLendOfferFactory
    function getActiveOrders(
        uint offset,
        uint limit
    ) public returns (DLOImplementation.LendInfo[] memory) {
        uint length = limit;
        if (length > activeOrdersCount) {
            length = activeOrdersCount;
        }

        DLOImplementation.LendInfo[]
            memory result = new DLOImplementation.LendInfo[](length - offset);

        for (uint i = 0; (i + offset) < limit; i++) {
            if ((i + offset) > (activeOrdersCount) - 1) {
                break;
            }
            result[i] = DLOImplementation(allActiveLendOrders[offset + i])
                .getLendInfo();
        }

        return result;
    }
}

DLOImplementation:
contract DLOImplementation is ReentrancyGuard, Initializable {
    address aggregatorContract;
    address factoryContract;
    bool public isActive;
    uint lastUpdate;

    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    struct LendInfo {
        address lendOrderAddress; // address of the lend order
        bool perpetual; // if the loan is perpetual --> every time the loan is paid back, the amount is available again here
        bool lonelyLender; // if the loan is only for one lender, if true, the loan is not available for other lenders
        bool[] oraclesPerPairActivated; // oracles activated for each pair
        uint[] maxLTVs; // max LTV for each collateral
        uint apr; // annual percentage rate you want to lend the tokens for
        uint maxDuration; // max duration of the loan
        uint minDuration; // min duration of the loan
        address owner; // owner of the lend order
        address principle; // address of the principle token
        address[] acceptedCollaterals; // address of the accepted collaterals
        address[] oracle_Collaterals; // address of the oracles for each collateral
        uint[] maxRatio; // max ratio for each collateral
        address oracle_Principle; // address of the oracle for the principle token
        uint startedLendingAmount; // initial amount of the principle token that is available for lending
        uint availableAmount; // amount of the principle token that is available for lending
    }
}

In the logs, it's showing this error:
Type struct DLOImplementation.LendInfo[] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct DLOImplementation.LendInfo[] memory. Solidity(9574)

Which doesn't make sense since they are the same.
Here's the test function:
function testPoC() public {        
    DLOImplementation.LendInfo[] memory lendInfo = DLOFactoryContract.getActiveOrders(0, type(uint256).max);
}


Have you created multiple copies of the same struct LendInfo that you're referencing? Because, it's not showing the error on my end when I'm using the same struct across different contracts. You can refer to this gist that I've created with minimal code instantiating struct instance with dummy values.
